# App is crashing when I use pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm finishing up the last bits of the login and signup screens of my app, but I am running into an error when I use backspace to log the user out of the dashboard.

It's actually very situational. If I was to...

1. Start on the main menu page
2. Sign in
3. Log out from the dashboard by doing `pushnamedandRemoveUntil` when the user presses the back key on their phone
4. repeat steps 1-3

...then everything works perfectly. But if I pressed the back key on the main menu(which would cause the app to go to sleep because there is no screen to go back to), reopen the app on my phone, and repeat steps 1-3, then I will get an error that says

```
The following RangeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: -1
```

Outside of what the error code is saying, I am not sure on how to resolve the issue.

Main.dart:

```
String host = Platform.environment['MONGO_DART_DRIVER_HOST'] ?? '127.0.0.1';
// String port = Platform.environment['MONGO_DART_DRIVER_PORT'] ?? '27017';
var port = 4000;
void main() async{
  test();
  runApp(juice_fit_life());
   // var db = Db('mongodb://192.168.1.1:27017/juicefit');
   // await db.open();
   // print('Connected to Database');
}
class juice_fit_life extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var routes = {
      Start.id:(context) => Start(),
      SignIn.id: (context) => SignIn(),
      SignUp.id:(context) => SignUp(),
      MemberSignUp.id:(context)=>MemberSignUp(),
      MemberSignUpGoals.id:(context)=>MemberSignUpGoals(),
      MemberEndUserLicense.id:(context)=>MemberEndUserLicense(),
      TrainerSignUp.id:(context) => TrainerSignUp(),
      TrainerEndUserLicense.id:(context) => TrainerEndUserLicense(),
      UserMainMenu.id:(context) => UserMainMenu(),
      PlanInfo.id:(context) => PlanInfo(),
      TrainerMainMenu.id:(context) => TrainerMainMenu()
    };
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider<GoalData>(create: (_) => GoalData()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<StudentSignUpData>(create: (_) => StudentSignUpData()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<TrainerSignUpData>(create: (_) => TrainerSignUpData()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<PlanData>(create: (_) => PlanData()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<SignInData>(create: (_)=> SignInData())],
      child: MaterialApp(
        initialRoute:Start.id ,
        onGenerateRoute: (settings){
          WidgetBuilder builder;
          Map arguments = settings.arguments;
          if ( settings.name == PlanInfo.id){
            builder = (context,)=> PlanInfo(
              name:arguments["name"],
              author: arguments["auth"],
              intropar: arguments["intro"],
              authorinfo: arguments['authInfo'],
              comments:arguments['comments'],
              authpic: arguments['picture']);
          }
          else{
            builder = (context,) => routes[settings.name](context);
          }
          return CustomPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings);
          // return PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2)=>routes[settings.name](context),
          //     transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0)
          // );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
Future<http.Response> test() {
  return http.get('http://192.168.1.4:3000/');
```

sign_in.dart:

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget{
  static String id = 'signIn';
  @override
  _SignIn createState()=> _SignIn();
}
class _SignIn extends State<SignIn>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading:IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Consumer<SignInData>(
        builder: (context,data,child){
          return ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 300.0,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          onChanged: (String value){
                            data.name = value;
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(focusedBorder:new UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white,width: 3.0)) ,enabledBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white,width: 3.0)),hintText: 'User Name',hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white) ),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          obscureText: true,
                          enableSuggestions: false,
                          autocorrect: false,
                          onChanged: (String value){
                            data.password = value;
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(focusedBorder:new UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white,width: 3.0)) ,enabledBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white,width: 3.0)),hintText: 'Password',hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white) ),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                child: data.badinput == false ? Text("Wrong User or Password",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 15.0)):SizedBox()
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SquareButton(
                            color:Colors.white,
                            pressed: () async{
                              hasher hash = new hasher();
                              print(hash.hashpass(data.password).toString());
                              final text =  await data.checkUser(data.name,hash.hashpass(data.password).toString());
                                if(text == false){
                                  print("result${text}");
                                  data.badinput = false;
                                }
                                else{
                                  if(text["userType"] == "trainer"){
                                    Provider.of<TrainerSignUpData>(context, listen: false).trainerData.userName = data.name;
                                    if (text["eulaAccept"] == false){
                                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, TrainerEndUserLicense.id,(r)=>false);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, TrainerMainMenu.id,(r)=>false);
                                    }
                                  }
                                  else{
                                    Provider.of<StudentSignUpData>(context, listen: false).studentData.userName = data.name;
                                    if (text["eulaAccept"] == false){
                                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MemberEndUserLicense.id,(r)=>false);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, UserMainMenu.id,(r)=>false);
                                    }
                                  }
                                  print("result: ${text["eulaAccept"]}");
                                  // Navigator.pushNamed(context, UserMainMenu.id);
                                }
                                data.notifyListeners();
                            },
                            butContent: Text('Sign In', style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
                            buttonwidth:150.0
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

User_Main_Menu.dart:

```
class UserMainMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = "UserMainMenu";

  _UserMainMenu createState() => _UserMainMenu();
}

class _UserMainMenu extends State<UserMainMenu> {
  int currentpage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffE5DDDD),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Dashboard"),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff32416F),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: (){
          var baseDialog = CustomAlertBox(
            infolist: <Widget>[
              Text(
                  "Do you want to sign out and close the app?"),
            ],
            actionlist: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Yes"),
                onPressed: () {
                  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => Start()
                        ),
                        ModalRoute.withName(Start.id)
                    );
                  });
                  // Provider.of<TrainerSignUpData>(context,listen: false).resetData();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("No"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(
                      false);
                },
              )
            ],
          );
          return showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => baseDialog);
        },
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Consumer<PlanData>(builder: (context, data, child) {
            if(currentpage == 0){
              return Center(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                    child: new ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: data.plans.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              PlanBanner(
                                name:data.plans[index]["name"],
                                author:data.plans[index]["author"],
                                img: data.plans[index]["picture"],
                                pressed: (){
                                  // Navigator.push(
                                  //   context,
                                  //     MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => PlanInfo(),
                                  //         settings: RouteSettings(
                                  //             arguments: {"name": data.plans[index]["name"]}
                                  //         ))
                                  // );
                                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(PlanInfo.id,arguments:{
                                    "data":data.plans[index]["name"],
                                    "auth":data.plans[index]["author"],
                                    "intro":"",
                                    "authInfo":"",
                                    "comments":"",
                                    "picture": ""
                                  });
                                  print(index);
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 20.0,
                              )
                            ],
                          );
                        })),
              );
            }
            else{
              return Center(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                    child: new ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: data.plans.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                          PlanBanner(
                          name:data.plans[index]["name"],
                            author:data.plans[index]["author"],
                            img: data.plans[index]["picture"],
                              pressed: (){
                                print(index);
                              }
                          ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 20.0,
                              )
                            ],
                          );
                        })),
              );
            }
          }),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Material(
              elevation: 0.0,
              color: currentpage == 0 ? Color(0xff32416F) : Colors.black,
              child: MaterialButton(
                child: Text(
                  "Available Plans",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentpage = 0;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Material(
              elevation: 0.0,
              color: currentpage == 1 ? Color(0xff32416F) : Colors.black,
              child: MaterialButton(
                child: Text("My Plans", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentpage = 1;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to solve this problem is by using `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement()` from your login screen to your dashboard/main screen because when you do that, you will be replacing the first route of the stack (which was the login) for the main screen and when you press the back button, you just need to do `Navigator.pop(context)` and it will close the app. The same thing will work for the logout, you can just use `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement()` to the login screen again.

Comment: Hi, Kennedy. This actually did the trick. Thank you for your help! Sorry for such a late response, however.